# Problem with matplotlib contourf's levels

Tags: python, matplotlib, knn

I'm trying to illustrate the decision boundaries of KNN algorithm using *meshgrid* and *contourf*. It is working ok when I have less than five different labels in my data. However, when the classes are more than five, matplotlib is sort of ignoring the number of levels I'm passing to *contourf* and draws one less.

> note that my classes won't exceed 10

The following code is for drawing the contours.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

color_lis =  ['black','red','blue','green','gold','pink','cyan','peru','silver','purple'] 

def createPlot(num_of_classes, ax_idx , ax):

    x_linspace = np.linspace(-1,1 , num = 101)
    y_linspace = np.linspace(1,-1 , num = 101)
    xm, ym = np.meshgrid(x_linspace, y_linspace)
    lm = np.zeros(xm.shape)

    for i in range(xm.shape[0]):
            c = 0
            l = 0
            for j in range(xm.shape[1]):
                if c % num_of_classes == 0:
                    l += 1
                    l %= num_of_classes 

                lm[i,j] = l
                c += 1
    ax[ax_idx].set_aspect('equal')
    ax[ax_idx].contourf( 
            xm, ym, lm , colors = color_lis[ : num_of_classes + 1] , levels = num_of_classes ,
            alpha = 0.35 , antialiased = True 
        )
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1 , ncols = 2)

createPlot(4, 0 , ax) #This will create 5 levels of different colors, black-red-blue-green-yellow
createPlot(5, 1 , ax) #Instead of creating 6 levels, this also created 5 levels as the previous line
```

Full code available at [github repo](https://github.com/ark1375/ML_Visual).

Works fine for five classes.
[image]

When classes equal six or more, the plot is wrong.
[image]

Comment: Please make your code to be a MWE. Linking to your full code does not make your error easily reproducible.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I've made sure of that. The code is edited.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Your code does still not reproduce your problem. Try to boil down your code as much as possible so that it is still showing this issue. Then copy/paste the **complete** code that is needed to reproduce your problem into your question

Comment: Just give matplotlib the levels you want rather than the number of levels.

Comment: @FlyingTeller Ok, this time it is an MWE. I made sure of that.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I tried that too. Didn't work. I think there is something about these levels that I don't quite understand. I updated the code btw. If you take a look at it you will see what I mean.

Comment: Well, "didn't work" is a little too vague.  My guess would be you are setting the levels equal to your classes whereas you should set them between the classes.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Didn't work means that it created the same result as the current code. What do you mean between classes? I don't get it.

Comment: If your classes are 1, 2, 3, 4, set the levels to 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, and 4.5